# Session Data overwriting in a two page form PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

To register a user, I am using a form that consists of two pages. the first form(addUser.php) sends the data over post to the second form(plz.php). In the second form I save the post values from the previous page in session variables, for example

```
     $_SESSION['phone1'] = $_POST['telnr'];
```

I have checked and the data is sent correctly to the second form. 
The second form has only one dropdown and after an option is selected, it is supposed to save all data in the database. 
The problem is that when I send the second form, all session variables are overwritten and I get a error message "email cannot be null". I am assuming the other variables are overwritten too.
I have tried so far saving the session data in an array and then extracting it but no luck.
The second form looks like this. And yes, sessions are started at the top of each file.

```
    $_SESSION['email1'] = $_POST['email'];
    $_SESSION['passwort1'] = $_POST['passwort'];
    $_SESSION['vname1'] = $_POST['vname'];
    $_SESSION['fname1'] = $_POST['fname'];
    $_SESSION['phone1'] = $_POST['telnr'];
    $_SESSION['firma1'] = $_POST['firmen_name'];
    $_SESSION['ad11'] = $_POST['adresse1'];
    $_SESSION['ad21'] = $_POST['adresse2'];
    $_SESSION['kr1'] = $_POST['kreis'];
    //$_SESSION["plz1"] = $_POST['plz'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    // Passwort wird gehasht und in der Datenbank gespeichert, bcrypt 
    algorithm, cost = 10, salt wurde automatisch generiert und ist unique
    $hash = password_hash($_SESSION['passwort1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $insert = "INSERT INTO users 
    (email,passwort,vname,fname,firmen_name,telnr, userlevel, active, 
    adresse1, adresse2, kreis, plz) VALUES 
    (:email,:hash,:vname,:fname,:firma,:phone,1,0, :adresse1, :adresse2, 
    :kreis, :plz)";
                $prepStmt = $pdo->prepare($insert);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("email", $_SESSION['email1']);    
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("hash", $hash);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("vname", $_SESSION['vname1']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("fname", $_SESSION['fname1']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("firma", $_SESSION['firma1']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("phone", $_SESSION['phone1']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("adresse1", $_SESSION['ad11']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("adresse2", $_SESSION['ad21']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("kreis", $_SESSION['kreis1']);
                $prepStmt ->bindParam("plz", $_POST["plz1"]);
                $prepStmt ->execute();
                header("Location: users.php");
                exit();
  }else{
  ?>
  <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-7">
            <form action="plz.php" method="post" class="text-center col-md-
  offset-0.5 ">
            <!-- more form -->
```

Comment: So what I am asking for are suggestions on how can I solve the overwriting problem.

Comment: "all session variables are overwritten" - Then just don't overwrite them.

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear, I need suggestions on how I can transfer the form data from the first form to the second one and how to save data from both forms without the second one overwriting the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use third page to save `plz.php` contents (the list) and values in the session.

It is clear that your session data is rewritten by null values when you submit the second form elements to the same page.

So you may change the form action like the following:

```
<form action="third.php" method="post" class="text-center col-md-
  offset-0.5 ">
```

Or you can send the second form `plz` using the GET method and change its requesting value from `$_POST` to `$_GET`. But Keep in mind to check if the `$_POST` empty to not set session!

Comment: thank you, I used this and extracted the session variables in the third page.

Answer (score 0):

Your $_SESSION array is being overwritten because you're overwriting it on form submission. Assign the values to the session array ONLY if it's NOT submit...

```
if (! isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $_SESSION['email1'] = $_POST['email'];
   $_SESSION['passwort1'] = $_POST['passwort'];
   // ...
}
```

So when the form is submitted your session is NOT overwritten, you only get the values for the sql query and do the location header and exit